# Run a different window manager in a specific workspace in XMonad

Tags: xorg, xmonad

I usually use XMonad as window manager. When playing around with GUI programming I sometimes just want to see how the windows would look under Compiz for example.

So is it possible to run another window manager, say Compiz, on a specific workspace under XMonad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nested X11 sessions are possible with [Xephyr](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Xephyr), see this example [from the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xephyr):
[image: nested X11 sessions using Xephyr screenshot]

This is independent of the "base" WM (XMonad), since it's just another X11 client for it to take care of.  That said, I have no idea about accelerated graphics in Xephyr, i.e. if Compiz is usable this way...

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question in principle (thus I am accepting it, but see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/116936/how-can-i-run-a-unity-session-inside-xephyr)

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can start another session from your login manager (while your main session keeps alive) and login as another user configured to use the window manager of your choice.

`LightDM` and `GDM` allow for that, and maybe other login manager. You can then switch back to your original session with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> or similar.